# How to call a Javascript function with arguments from .js file in karate feature file

Tags: karate

Lets say I created javascript functions in functions js file.

`function getReviews(reviews){

     var length_reviews = reviews.length
     return length_reviews
}`

`function getReviewsLength(reviewLength){

     return reviewLength 
}`

Here in function `getReviews` argument `reviews` is an array.
Now how will I call `getReviews` function in one feature file.
When I tried below code

`* def jsFunction = call read('functions.js')
 * def review = jsFunction.getReviews(reviewFromFeatureFile)`

I am getting an error of

`Cannot read property "length" from undefined`

I already printed `reviewFromFeatureFile` and its coming correctly in print statement.

Comment: Thanks @Peter but in my case as the function is complex one so how will i pass arguments in that function from other feature file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter mentioned above you can keep you js inline on your feature

```
* def reviews = [{"r1":2},{"r1":3},{"r1":4}]
* def getReviews = function(reviews){ return reviews.length }
* def getReviewsLength = getReviews(reviews)
* print getReviewsLength
```

In this example, it should print 3.

For more other options for handling javascript or other reusable modules in karate, please refer to this article

[Organizing re-usable functions in karate](https://medium.com/@babusekaran/organizing-re-usable-functions-karatedsl-575cd76daa27)

Answer (score 0):

In one "common" feature file, define multiple methods like this:

```
* def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
* def now = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() }
```

You can now call this feature like this:

```
* call read('common.feature')
```

And now all the functions in that feature are available for use:

```
* def id = uuid()
* def time = now()
```